# How would I pull the data from a JSON response when the field name contains the @ character

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, postman, special-characters

I am trying to set a variable to a piece of data, however the object name contains the character @.

I have tests using to.include for specific data that will always be there, but this field would be dynamic. I've also tried stringifying the response to see if I can pull it that way

```
pm.environment.set("item",jsonData.object.@item)
```

I am trying to pull the information in this field to use as a variable. The field in the response contains a value.

Comment: jsonData['@item']

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties of an object also in the following way:

```js
pm.environment.set('item',jsonData['@item'])
```

Comment: When it's inside of an object, it does not look like it's grabbing it.
The full thing would be pm.environment.set('item',jsondata.object1.object2.@item);

It does not look like it works in this context

Comment: Hi @AlaricBloodmoon, apologies for not seen this sooner. Please, feel free to edit the snippet to account for any mistakes :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yo can do it like this.

```
jsonData['@item']
```